# switch between combobox and textfield dynamically extjs4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a checkbox on a website, and a combobox. When that checkbox is checked, I want to change the combobox into a textfield (and of course conserve any selected value and put it in the textfield). When the checkbox is unchecked I wanna go back to display the combobox (and it's previously selected value).

Any idea how I can achieve this in ExtJS4 Please?

Thank you

Comment: You can't change the field type, so just have 2 fields and hide the not relevant one. Listen to the change event on the checkbox and swap appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Well youd start by having a listener in your controller that will run when the checkbox gets checked. In that function you should be able to pull the value from the combobox, store it in a temp variable, create (or probably unhide) your textfield, and put your temp variable value in there.

Then write the opposite for a uncheck listener action

Are you working in MVC?

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

We've implemented a similar approach.

Put a combobox inside a container and add a textfield to it. Add listeners to checkbox and use `combobox.hide()` and `textfield.show()` in handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('MyComboBox',{
    extend:'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    initComponent:function() {
        this.originalForceSelection = this.forceSelection;
        this.callParent(arguments);
        if(this.textFieldMode) this.setTextfieldMode(true);
    },
    function setTextfieldMode(bool)
    {
        if(bool) {
            this.forceSelection=false;
            this.setHideTrigger(true);
        } else {
            this.setHideTrigger(false);
            this.forceSelection=this.originalForceSelection;
        }
    }
});
```